# Connect to IBM Cognos BI in java using Rest call?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I have setup an LDAP server on cognos BI and am trying to setup something in Java to connect to it using name/pass.
I did see there are some java codes like logon BUT my 10.x install cognos analytics doesnt have the SDK or the java directories so I have no idea how to get them working.

Can i do the same thing via a TM1 rest call?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use parameterized URLs as noted here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_dg_sdk.doc/c_performing_tasks_using_urls.html#Performing_Tasks_Using_URLs

I think sign in was not introduced until 11.0.6+
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.wig_cr.doc/c_wig_cr_create_custom_url.html

The following covers using postman with the TM1 Rest API,  there is a step by step on how to use your CAM security

https://code.cubewise.com/blog/mastering-the-tm1-rest-api-with-postman

Example of login URL can be found here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/parameterized-url-perform-login-and-open-dashboard-or-report

Comment: So after i make that call in java, do i have access to other reporting TM1 features? The goal is to authenticate against LDAP and then in java make actions so i dont need to authenticate myself against the LDAP anymore. Also, i dont think i have 11.X yet

Comment: Added a TM1 rest api example URL with CAM security

Comment: Hi, I looked at the links and i can't figure out what to do if i just want to login using the user/pass one time but not open any reports. I see:
http(s)://WEBSERVERNAME/ALIAS/bi/v1/disp?CAM_action=logonAs&CAMNamespace=NAMESPACEID&CAMUsername=USERID&CAMPassword=PASSWORD&m_redirect=/ALIAS/bi/?pathRef=.public_folders%2FSamples%2FReports%2FCustomer+claim+analysis&format=HTML&prompt=true&action=run

I am not sure what to do with the pathRef or  i need to redirect somewhere? Thanks.